# biblatex and \filteror to produce a combined list of abbreviations

Tags: biblatex, biber, shorthands

My end goal is to try and produce a combined list of abbreviations from a number of fields. (I'm happy to hear if I'm going about this in the wrong way.) Note too that I realise that my implementation assumes that a particular entry will only include one abbreviation. I don't necessarily want to make this assumption, so comments on this also welcome.

I currently have two problems:

- I can't get `\filteror` to work to return (say) entries with a shorthand field or a shortseries field. Using `\filteror` seems to return all entries.
- The label width gets set automatically to the widest shorthand. I'm not sure how to get it set the the combined widest (say) shorthand and shortseries. (Although, I think I can work this out maybe).

Here's a MWE with what I currently have. I've printed (Author Year) to show that \filteror returns an entry not containing either shorthand or shortseries.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{talbert:1992,
  author = {Talbert, Charles H.},
  title = {Reading John: A Literary and Theological Commentary on the Fourth Gospel and the Johannine Epistles},
  location = {New York},
  publisher = {Crossroad},
  date = {1992}
}
@book{hofius:1989,
  author = {Hofius, Otfried},
  title = {Paulusstudien},
  series = {Wissenschaftliche Untersuchungen zum Neuen Testament},
  shortseries = {WUNT},
  number = {51},
  location = {T\"{u}bingen},
  publisher = {Mohr Siebeck},
  date = {1989}
}
@mvbook{TDNT,
  editor = {Kittel, Gerhard and Friedrich, Gerhard},
  title = {Theological Dictionary of the New Testament},
  shorthand = {TDNT},
  translator = {Bromiley, Geoffrey W.},
  volumes = {10},
  location = {Grand Rapids},
  publisher = {Eerdmans},
  date = {1964/1976}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibenvironment{abbreviations}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shortseries}%
      \printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareBiblistFilter{abbreviations}{
  \filteror{%
    \filter[type=field,filter=shorthand]
    \filter[type=field,filter=shortseries]
  }
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{abbreviations}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \iffieldundef{shortseries}{}{\printfield{series}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext{\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro*{cite}}}%
}
\defbibcheck{abbreviations}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{\strfield{series}}
      {\skipentry}
      {\savefieldcs{series}{\strfield{series}}}%   
    }}
\DeclareSortingScheme{abbreviations}{%
  \sort{%
    \field{shorthand}%
    \field{shortseries}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\autocite{talbert:1992}
\autocite{hofius:1989}
\autocite{TDNT}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some testing shows leads me to believe you really have encountered an issue here. I have complained about this at the `biblatex` bugtracker [#337](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/337).

Comment: Out of interest, what is `\savefieldcs{series}{\strfield{series}}` for?

Comment: Thanks, @moewe. Appreciate you looking at it. And especially thanks for reporting the bug. I agree that the documentation is not very helpful for either \filter or \filteror. An I could not find an example of \filteror in use **anywhere** on the Internet! `\savefieldcs{series}{\strfield{series}}` is taken from page 78 of the biblatex manual. It defines a command from the value of series. If multiple books from the same series appear, subsequent entries are skipped by the `\ifcsdef` check.

Comment: Indeed, the only mentions of `\filteror` Google can find is your question and the manual with its short description of `\filteror`. I'm beginning to understand what `\savefieldcs{series}{\strfield{series}}` does, I think you might be missing a `\skipentry` in `\iffieldundef{series}{}` it should be `\iffieldundef{series}{\skipentry}`.

Comment: `\iffieldundef{series}{}` is ok. My actual `\defbibcheck` macro is more complex. In theory, the filter should filter out entries without a series in the above code. I assume that there will be no duplicate shorthands, so no need to include this in `\defbibcheck`

Comment: That gave me an idea, I think it could be possible to move all the filtering from `\DeclareBiblistFilter` to the bibcheck. I don't have the time to investigate that right now, but will try to do so later.

Comment: Yes, this might work. I could appropriately nest the checks in `\defbibcheck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Got it for both problems. Thanks to @moewe, I've just done the entire filter in `\defbibcheck`. I've also found the solution to the label width problem (just a matter of using the max of `\shortserieswidth` and `\shorthandwidth`).

Any suggested improvement welcome. (My actual code also handles shortjournal.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{talbert:1992,
  author = {Talbert, Charles H.},
  title = {Reading John: A Literary and Theological Commentary on the Fourth Gospel and the Johannine Epistles},
  location = {New York},
  publisher = {Crossroad},
  date = {1992}
}
@book{hofius:1989,
  author = {Hofius, Otfried},
  title = {Paulusstudien},
  series = {Wissenschaftliche Untersuchungen zum Neuen Testament},
  shortseries = {WUNT},
  number = {51},
  location = {T\"{u}bingen},
  publisher = {Mohr Siebeck},
  date = {1989}
}
@mvbook{TDNT,
  editor = {Kittel, Gerhard and Friedrich, Gerhard},
  title = {Theological Dictionary of the New Testament},
  shorthand = {\emph{TDNT}},
  translator = {Bromiley, Geoffrey W.},
  volumes = {10},
  location = {Grand Rapids},
  publisher = {Eerdmans},
  date = {1964/1976}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newlength{\abbrevwidth}
\def\setmaxlength#1#2{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr#2>\dimexpr#1
    \global\setlength{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\defbibenvironment{abbreviations}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shortseries}%
      \printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setmaxlength{\abbrevwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setmaxlength{\abbrevwidth}{\shortserieswidth}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{abbreviations}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \iffieldundef{shortseries}{}{\printfield{series}}%
}
\defbibcheck{abbreviations}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{\strfield{series}}
      {\skipentry}
      {\savefieldcs{series}{\strfield{series}}}%   
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{shortseries}}
  }
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\DeclareSortingScheme{abbreviations}{%
  \sort{%
    \field{shorthand}%
    \field{shortseries}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\autocite{talbert:1992}
\autocite{hofius:1989}
\autocite{TDNT}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]